# Running a script from a jQuery dialog button?

Tags: jquery, function, dialog

I'm trying to get my dialog "Okay" button to execute a replay function to open a web page in a new window. But the command doesn't seem to run from clicking the button. Can someone please rearrange the code and i would be very thankful if you could explain it too. Thanks! P.S The code is inside the head tag.

```
<script>
function jobbig() {
    var tag = $('<div>JOBBIGT</div>');
    tag.dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Okay: function () {

                flag = 1;

                function replay() {
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        open("file:///C:/Users/elev/Desktop/index.html", "New_Window");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: try `function jobbig() {
    var tag = $('<div>JOBBIGT</div>');
    tag.dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Okay: function () {
                replay(1);
            }
        }
    });
}

function replay(flag) {
    if (flag == 1) {
        open("file:///C:/Users/elev/Desktop/index.html", "New_Window");
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
<script>
function replay() 
{
    if (flag==1) 
       {
           window.open("file:///C:/Users/elev/Desktop/index.html"); 
       }
}

function jobbig() { 
   var tag = $('<div>JOBBIGT</div>'); 
   tag.dialog({
   modal: true, buttons:
    {
        Okay: function() {
              flag = 1;
              replay();
            }
    } 
  }); 
}
</script>
```